# How to make Custom Hook returns a function, which uses another hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a custom hook, which I want to use at multiple places in another components like a function, which takes in parameter (E.i For `useNavigate()` from `react-router-dom-v6`, we use it as `const navigate = useNavigate()` then `navigate('./url/to/navigate')` can be used at multiple places).

But in the custom hook, I want to process that parameters value through another custom hook. This is what I tried but React does not allow me to have hooks inside function like so:

```js
//useCustomHook.js
function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}
...
export default function useCustomHook() {
    function processingData(currentState){
        const previousState = usePrevious(currentState);    //React does not allow to have hook here
        return process(currentState, previousState);
    }
    return processingData;
}

//Component.js
...
const cusHook = useCustomHook();
...
useEffect(()=>{
   cusHook(state1)
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
   cusHook(state2)
},[temp])
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can use hook inside pure javascript function. Why not doing something like this:

```
   export default function useCustomHook(currentState) {
        const previousState = usePrevious(currentState);
        const processingData = () => {
               return process(currentState, previousState);
        }
       return processingData;
   }
```

Comment: If I do it this way, then in `Component.js`, I will have to create a bunch of instances of custom hooks for different states. Moreover, it wouldn't be flexible to execute the hook on some certain state cases, like when state results depends on each other, for example, state1 update, then compute state2, then hook compute state2.

Comment: I agree that it would be much easier with solution you thought that will work. Regarding multiple instances of custom hooks, I am pretty sure it is possible to create hook that will work same as this one but for multiple arguments(to be dynamic), eg: `const [prevA, prevB, prevC] = useMultiplePrevious(a, b, c)`, and then on top of this it is possible to create something analogous to `useCustomHook` that will also work with multiple values, so you can avoid calling same hook multiple times inside your component.